# How do I get negative margins working properly?

Tags: html, css

This is my [site](http://speakingwithpictures.com/about).

I'm attempting to get the black div to break out of the parent div and span the width of the browser.

I'm trying to do this with negative margins.

Like so

```
.aboutTop {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-right: -100px;
}
```

Note: I've tried it with `margin-left: -100%;` just using the above to see what's going wrong.

However, the margin-right isn't working.

It just shifts the box to the left by 100px.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The margin-right property is funny to play with, when you are left aligned, it creates space to right instead of moving to right. Having answered on of your previous related question, I must say, just increase the width to fit the screen, instead of adding negative right margin. You got the box to left corner, increase width now, and make it fit the page.

HERE's what you must do.
Pick up the entire division and move it out of the parent that is containing its width
USE:

```
#yourdiv{
position:absolute;
top:200px;
left:0;
background:black;
width:100%;
height:200px;

}
```

Do it the simplest way... Instead of messing around. Get it out of that damn parent div.

Comment: Making the div wider – lets say 200% – results in extra scrolling on the right.

Comment: Calculate dude... try different values or pick up the entire division and paste it out of parent division. see the edits I am making

Answer (score 0):

- You set your width to 100% (so thats 100% of the parent)
- You say you want to break out of the parent width at both sides!
  **This goes against each other**

The left margin is doing its job like supposed and the right margin isn't because the 100% limit is reached!

Delete the width:100%; and you're good to go!

[EDIT]
Above doesn't solves the 100% width of the browser issue
Mayby thats possible with some javascript?

```
var screenwidth = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
```

and then something like

```
document.getElementById('aboutTop').style.width = screenwidth;
```

This requirers you to change the class='aboutTop' to id='aboutTop'

Comment: yes i noticed! this only solves the 'breaking out of parent' issue

Comment: @Michael What about using `max-width: 100%`?

Comment: @cimmanon And still holds the 100% width inherit from the parent. He wants to break out of the 100% width of the parent and get the 100% width of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin-right` and adjust it with `margin-left`.

Comment: @Anuji Adjusting `margin-left`does nothing except move it left and right. I't doesn't expand the width of the browser.